# Burns and Gidea's differential geometry/topology: $\Bbb S^2$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R$!!

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

[Exercise 1.15.2 of Burns and Gidea's differential geometry/topology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Differential_Geometry_and_Topology/tV9sTDnaf40C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA66&printsec=frontcover) states that:

> **Exercise 1.15.2:** Consider a bijection between the real line $\Bbb R$ and the sphere $\Bbb S^2$
> (such a bijection exists since these are sets with same cardinality). Show
> that the composition of the local parametrizations of $\Bbb S^2$ from above with this bijection defines a smooth structure on $\Bbb R$. Show that $\Bbb R$ endowed
> with this smooth structure is **diffeomorphic** to the sphere $\Bbb S^2$. With this
> smooth structure, the real line is a sphere! The point of this exercise
> is to stress that a manifold is not just a set that can be endowed with
> some structure, but the set together with that structure.

If so what is the role of invariance of dimensions? It seems that this exercise is a serious mistake by authors!!

In the page 67, [exercise 1.15.5](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Differential_Geometry_and_Topology/tV9sTDnaf40C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA67&printsec=frontcover) claims that

> **Exercise 1.15.5:**  Provide the unit cube $Q\subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$
> with a smooth structure. The point of this exercise it to illustrate that **a
> smooth manifold may not look smooth**! Of course this smooth structure
> is not compatible with the smooth structure of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

Is the claimed statement correct? I have no idea about $n>2$ but in $n=1,2$ I think it is wrong by unique differential structure in dim$<4$!

Comment: They are not even homeorphic. What am I missing here? Dont we need at least a homeo to construct a diffeo?

Comment: I think like you.

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ aren't homeomorphic if they both have their usual topologies, but surely this construction induces a non-standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Invariance of domain says no such bijection can be a homeomorphism. The construction given here equips $\mathbb{R}$ with a completely different topology. The exercise is correct, the point is to force you to think about this sort of thing.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: In the case of diffeomorphisms, the dimensions of domain and codomain are equal but here is not.

Comment: The point is that dimension is not a property of the *set*, but of the topology. The underlying set is $\mathbb{R}$, but this set is endowed with a 2-dimensional topology.

Comment: I am confused!! Lets to ask this instead: The topology of $\Bbb R$ mentioned in the exercise above, is compact? how many ends it has?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is that you endow the set $\mathbb R$ with a topology (and a smooth structure) which **has nothing to do** with its usual topology (and smooth structure).

In fact, the general construction is this:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $X$ be set and $h : X \to M$ be a bijection. Then there exists a unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $h$ becomes a homeomorphism. Moreover, there exists a unique smooth structure on $(X,\tau)$ such that $h$ becomes a diffeomorphism.

If you reflect upon this, there is no surprise in it. What is confusing you is this: We start with a smooth manifold $N$ and take a bijection $h : N \to M$. This map is not subject to any restrictions, it may not even be continuous. But it induces a smooth structure **on the set** $N$ such that $h$ becomes a diffeomorphism. But, as we have seen above, this smooth structure is not related to the original smooth structure of $N$.

Comment: So $\Bbb S^1\simeq \Bbb S^2\simeq \Bbb S^3\simeq \dots$ with appropriate topologies?

Comment: @C.F.G Yes. Any two sets with the same cardinality can be endowed with topologies making the resulting toplogical spaces homeomorphic.

Comment: The confusing thing, is to use the "wrong" notation. If you endow the underlying set of $\mathbb{S}^2$ (or any set with the same cardinality of the real numbers for that matter) with a topology (or a smooth structure) making it isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$, you should name it $\mathbb{S}^1$, not $\mathbb{S}^2$. After all, from the pure set theoritical point of view, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{S}^n$ etc... are all the "same" set.
When you write $\mathbb{S}^n$, a lot of implicit assumptions are made about the topology, smooth structure...

Comment: Hope my comment is not all the more confusing. =)

Comment: @Ahr Of course it is not really a good idea to speak about the **space** $S^k$ if it does not have its standard topology. This is a basic notational problem: Some objects have their well-known names, but the interpretion depends on the context. Is $S^k$ just a set or  a topological space or  a manifold or a group for $k =1, 3$ ?

Comment: The hard thing to do in this evil construction then would be to express the points without making reference to the isomorphism if I understood correctly.

Comment: $S^k$ are spaces by convention. The groups have their usual name $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$ repectively for $k=1,3$.

Comment: @Garmekain This is not true. $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$ are matrix groups and already on the level of sets different from $S^1$ and $S^3$. $S^1$ is group with respect to complex multiplication, $S^3$ wilt respect to quaternion multiplication.

Comment: I didn't thought of elements being the same. But $S^k$ are certainly considered spaces if no additional info is given, that's for sure.

Comment: @Ahr: thanks. So the authors are misusing of the name "real line"?

Comment: @PaulFrost: what about the second question? i.e. all we know that cube has corners but authors want to topologize it such that it becomes a smooth manifold but we are not talking about cube anymore after new topology. As you said cube is diffeomorphic to sphere. so this exercise is a duplicate I think.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. The authors only want to show that something which "obviously" seems to have corners may nevertheless be endowed with a smooth structure.

Comment: I have read and am reading many books for more than 10 years  but Now I realized this quote: **The more I read, the more I realize I don't know anything**. I don't know whether I am so stupid or math is so weird and wild!!

Comment: @C.F.G You are not stupid. Quote from Shakespeare's "Hamlet": *There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.*